# How to changes Struts 1.3 to Servlets?

Tags: jsp, dojo, jsp-tags, struts-1

I am using struts 1.3 version

Now,I want to change to servlet. So How can do that Please provide me steps

Answer (score 0):

- Business logic will remain as-is (see footnote)
- Translate every action into a servlet
- Rewrite all JSPs to remove Struts tags
- Implement form validation and data population

*If you have a poorly-architected application you'll find business logic in your actions. That's almost always bad.  Then you'd need to pick apart each and every action to determine what's part of the web layer and what's part of the business layer–this would be a good time to isolate that so you don't have to do it again later. It also makes it easier to test and reason about.*

Comment: Thank you. I have one more problem. I am using struts interceptors, controller, tiles, message resource and other struts-plugins. Now I`m a bit confusing how to map all those using servlets.

Comment: @venkatesh.mandadi Interceptors may map to filters, depends on what they're doing. Controllers are the servlets. Message resources are property files-standard I18N stuff. Tiles are probably replaceable by standard JSP templating, but it depends on how complex your tiles are and how much of Tiles you're actually using. "Other Struts plugins" is too vague to address.